# Как изменить стд. цвет border-a элемнета combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Использую comboBox со свойством в FlatStyle = Popup, стиль меняется, но бордюри устанавливаются в белый цвет, по ссылке фото, к сожалению сюда не получилось залить. Каким способом можно всё-таки установить нужный цвет [скриншиот](http://imglink.ru/show-image.php?id=5a7a8f8db1438eb86760dd33afcdfcfe) ?

Comment: Да ладно вам.. не ужели нет вариантов, может наследовать что и переопределить или все же делать через xaml, не хотел писать слово "xaml", дабы не слить сам вопрос.. думаю проще все должно быть, обычная "рамка") правда никакими методами подобраться не получилось.

Comment: @Agentura, о каком xaml идёт речь, если у вас winforms?

Comment: в плане перехода на wpf

Comment: Ну если в плане перехода на wpf, то заверните в <border> просто

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот [этот](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18172/Appearance-Customizable-ComboBox) компонент.

Comment: Не много не то, я имел ввиду просто установить цвет на бордюр, а эти предложенные страшные.. Но спасибо, если нет других вариантов, можно эти попилить/переделать.